# Ubuntu 18.04 failed to boot

Tags: boot, 18.04

I constantly check for updates and if there are any apps waiting to be upgraded to latest version,  `sudo apt upgrade` is used.
Then, I noticed that my nodejs version is still in *8.x*, I removed it and downloaded it from their official page and extracted it to `/opt/node/`.
Everything was working fine afterwards, I created new Laravel project with JetStream and all and discovered that my PHPMyAdmin is falling to connect. Quick fix was to restart my PC. That was the last time I was able to boot my PC. When I boot, here is the
[output when trying to boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1p9a.jpg)

P.S. I'm using Ubuntu as my only OS and it's been over a year I've been using it.